# Ruby on Rails PubNub subscribe as separate process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pubnub

I was consider using PubNub on my website.

In turn, I can subscribe to channels with PubNub.

However, I need to find a way to run a script that subscribes to channels with PubNub.

For example, according to their documentation http://www.pubnub.com/blog/ruby-push-api , it states "To listen for published messages, call the subscribe function. It is important to note: the subscribe function is blocking. You will want to run this function in a separate process."

Then PubNub provides the following code:

```
 ## Subscribe (Listen for Messages)
 pubnub.subscribe({
'channel ' => 'my_channel',
'callback' => lambda do |message|
    ## Message Received!!!
    puts(message['my_var']) ## print message
    return true             ## keep listening?
end
  })
```

I cannot think of a way to run this function as a "process."

Isn't there something like background jobs? Is this what I would need?

Appreciate any guidance.

Comment: You would just create a separate Ruby file and run it from the server's command line in a terminal. But after rereading your question, it seems as if you are trying to subscribe from the Ruby/server side via a browser app. You would be using Ruby to serve up the web page that contains the JavaScript that will subscribe and perhaps you have a separate Ruby script/process running on your server that publishes messages, or the JavaScript client will be publishing peer to peer with each other without your server being involved - which is the typical use case. Let me know if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get started with this (at this time) is to use the Ruby EventMachine async HTTP request method and the PubNub HTTP REST API.

1. EventMachine::Protocols::HttpClient2
   -> http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org/EventMachine/Protocols/HttpClient2.html
2. PubNub HTTP REST API
   -> http://www.pubnub.com/tutorial/http-rest-push-api

   ```
   conn = EM::Protocols::HttpClient2.connect 'pubsub.pubnub.com', 80
   req  = conn.get('/subscribe/SUBSCRIBE_KEY/CHANNEL/0/TIMETOKEN')
   ```

Note that this is not a full example, but a good starting point...  You must follow the HTTP REST Guide.

Comment: Can you explain more?  Where would I place this code?  For example, I created an .rb file, but when I do this my webbrowser just sits there loading because it made the connection

Comment: Best to follow the example provided in HttpClient2 in EventMachine Protocols - http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org/EventMachine/Protocols/HttpClient2.html

Comment: `        EM.run{
           conn = EM::Protocols::HttpClient2.connect 'pubsub.pubnub.com', 80

           req = conn.get('/')
           req.callback{ |response|
             p(response.status)
             p(response.headers)
             p(response.content)
           }
         }`

Comment: the documentation for PubNub is absolutely horrible. I do not think I am going to use it anymore.

Comment: We recognize that the docs were not optimal (OK, horrible and out of date) at the time you posted this. If it's not too late, take another look at our docs. I think you will be pleased. http://www.pubnub.com/docs/ruby/pubnub-ruby-sdk - That said, if you (Brian Rosedale) agree, it would be appreciated if you could update your feedback. If not, now worries.