# Asynchronous callbacks - PubNub, EventMachine, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eventmachine, pubnub

I'm subscribing to a PubNub channel through EventMachine, however I currently only receive one and only one message posted to the channel.

```
EventMachine.run {
pubnub.subscribe({
'channel'  => @channel,
'callback' => lambda do |message|
puts(message)
end  
})
}
```

In other words, I'm looking for a way to make the callbacks "more" asynchronous. I guess I could wrap it in a periodic_timer but I have a bad feeling about this approach. Are there any best practices in this field I should now about?

**Edit:**
The solution to my problems was to, first of all, add 'return true' in the subscribe loop so that it continues to listen. But more importantly, spawning EM in a new thread that listens to whatever channels needed and then dispatching it all to one channel that the client listens to. This solved my problems with handling multiple channels without either the server or client freezing/timing out/overflowing. See http://www.pubnub.com/blog/ruby-push-api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten to add:

```
return true
```

It now continues to listen. The stack overflows after a few minutes though, but that's another question.

Answer (score 1):

A new, completely rewritten PubNub version 3.3 gem is going to be released within 24 hours.

I'll alert you when it has been released, and if you experience any issues with this new gem, we'll troubleshoot it from there.

geremy

Comment: Sweet. Yeah please let me know when it's live and don't be shy to put in some hours on rookie-level RoR documentation :)

Comment: Its now released! https://rubygems.org/gems/pubnub-ruby The request core is natively EM.

Comment: @Oskare, just checking in, did you have a chance to test out this new version?

Comment: Thanks mate. I'm actually struggling with how to hook up EventMachine and PubNub to run as a separate process (much like this guy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395198/ruby-on-rails-pubnub-subscribe-as-separate-process) so haven't really had the opportunity to try out the new gem. When subscribing in a 'regular' eventmachine loop I get a timeout after around 1 minute and everything crashes. If you have any advice on this it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @oskare Can you email support at pubnub a minimal piece of code / app that reproduces the issue you are experiencing? I'm happy to take a look and see if we can't help figure it out for you.

Comment: Thanks but I got it working. Spawning EM in a new thread that listens to a few channels and then dispatching them all to one single channel that the client listens to seems to have solved it.

Comment: Great! Ping us if we can help with anything else!